# TCP Messages above a certain size (~1450) get "stuck"

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I am attempting to send packets of various length through my hardware and I have run into an issue when the packets reach a particular size, ~1450 bytes. Everything works fine when the packet size is less than ~1450 byte.

I have been debugging this issue with my NIC driver and outputting what I get right before I send data out. I can see the TCP handshake, and my packet when < ~1450 bytes is sent.

Once I try to send a packet over ~1450 bytes, I never see the TCP handshake, or the packet in my NIC driver. Therefore I am certain that the packet is lost somewhere in Linux... This looks to be some sort of error with packet fragmentation in Linux but I'm not sure.

**Has anyone encountered packet loss when attempting to send packets of a certain threshold, and in my case, ~1450 bytes in Linux?**

I am unsure of where to start looking to find out where my packet is being held up or why...

I am using Linux 3.10.39, it can't be changed. I have also increased the MTU size to a greater value in my NIC driver but it seems to have no affect and the packets of ~1450 bytes continue to get stuck.

I am using a basic Perl tcp server/client [found here](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-write-simple-tcp-server-and-client-in-perl.html) to test communication.

Comment: There is no such thing as a TCP message. It is a byte stream protocol. You don't have any basis for your expectation.

Comment: @user207421 if you send a message over TCP stream, you can still call it a message. And on the underlying level even TCP stream is broken into small units. The point of the question is that if OP sends large chunk of data over TCP stream, the stream gets stuck. This is pretty common issue if you have some experience with network applications. The answers describe it in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning off [Generic Segmentation Offload and Generic Receive Offload](https://docs.kernel.org/networking/segmentation-offloads.html) fixed the issue.

```
ethtool -K eth1 gso off
ethtool -K eth1 gro off
```

Answer (score 3):

This could be a symptom of your box or some router in between incorrectly dropping ICMP packets taking part in Path MTU discovery (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery). Could it be that something is throttling these, e.g. based on an assumption that ICMP is all about pings and therefore not important?

Comment: I am communicating over a media network and it very well could be that the cisco switch I am communicating through is causing problems. I will take a look into that

Comment: side note, I can ping

Comment: [IP Source Quench](http://networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/icmp/msg4.htm) may be causing control message loss. The gateway does not have to send it when it drops a datagram.

Answer (score 2):

TCP packets that exceed the network's MTU are supposed to get lost. Fragmentation severely degrades TCP performance, so allowing packets large enough to fragment is counter-productive.

Endpoints do [path MTU discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery), reducing the datagram size to get good performance. This is things working as intended and is not a problem. The endpoint will try smaller packets to discover the maximum packet size that can be sent without fragmentation and use that.

See Tomasz Noinski's answer discussing the possibility that a misconfigured firewall may be interfering with path MTU discovery. ICMP is an Internet host requirement and blocking it indiscriminately will break TCP.

Comment: I will look into the MTU discovery

Comment: Also to clarify, If I send a packet of size 2000 bytes over the network and the MTU is 1500, it should drop the packet all together correct? I guess I was under the impression that the packet would get fragmented into chunks to allow it to go through the network, so that 2000 byte message would get fragmented into a 1500 and 500 bytes message and then reassembled?

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz TCP implementations specifically request that their datagrams not be fragmented by setting the "Don't Fragment" bit in the IP header. TCP does its own segmentation anyway and fragmentation amplifies packet loss. (If 10% of packets are lost and you fragment a datagram into two packets, then the datagram loss rate is 19% and each lost datagram loses two packets full of data. Ouch.)

Comment: I am not familiar with networking and so I appreciate your insight, it's very helpful.